# Can I have a bean which defines type T, and a factory bean which returns type T?

Tags: java, spring, ioc-container

I have a request scoped bean which returns the current user:

```
<bean id="currentUserResolver" class="com.shutup.CurrentUserResolver" />

<bean scope="request" factory-bean="currentUserResolver" factory-method="getCurrentUser">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

This is so that I can autowire a User object and get the current user.  What I also want to do is modify my User class to have an init-method:

```
<bean id="user" class="com.shutup.model.User" init-method="postInitialize" />
```

If I do this, Spring complains:

```
No unique bean of type [com.shutup.model.User] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [user, currentUserResolver$created#0]
```

Is there a way to declaratively add my postInitialize method to User?  I believe I also have the option of User implementing an interface, but I'd rather not tie my code to Spring to closely.

CurrentUserResolver:

```
public class CurrentUserResolver
{
    static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CurrentUserResolver.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private UserFactory userFactory;

    public User getCurrentUser()
    {    
        log.info("attempting to get current user");

        User currentUser = null;

        if(SecurityContextHolder.getContext() != null &&
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() instanceof UserAuthentication)
        {
            UserAuthentication authentication = (UserAuthentication)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            User serializedUser = (User)authentication.getPrincipal();
            currentUser = this.userFactory.getUserFromTwitterId(serializedUser.getTwitterId());
        }

        return currentUser;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show your code in `CurrentUserResolver`

Comment: Your user bean shouldn't be a singleton, should it? Why don't you call your postInit method from the factory?

Comment: @abalogh I'd like the User to be able to postInitialize itself, but I could expose something to the factory...